# Multiple Ajax-calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't understand why the application is doing multiple ajax-calls.

Have a look at this directive:

```
gameApp.directive('mapActivity', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(function(scope) {
                angular.element('.click#1').addClass('dotted').html($("<img src='images/dot.png'>"));
                var j = null;
                for(var i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'lib/terrain.php',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        data: {i: i},
                        success: function(data) {
                            var randomRuta = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
                            angular.element('.click#'+randomRuta).addClass('monster').html($("<img src='images/blackdot.png' title='"+data+"'>"));

                        },
                        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(thrownError); }
                    });
                    j=i;
                }  
                angular.element('.click').click(function() {
                    if(angular.element(this).hasClass('monster'))
                    {
                        if(confirm('Vill du anfalla monster?'))
                        {
                            alert("Du vann");
                            angular.element('.click.monster'+j).empty();
                            angular.element('.click.monster').removeClass('monster'+j);

                            angular.element('.click.dotted').empty();
                            angular.element('.click.dotted').removeClass('dotted');
                            angular.element(this).addClass('dotted');
                            angular.element('.click.dotted').html($('<img src="images/dot.png">'));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        angular.element('.click.dotted').empty();
                        angular.element('.click.dotted').removeClass('dotted');

                        if(!angular.element(this).hasClass('dotted'))
                        {
                            angular.element(this).addClass('dotted');
                            angular.element(this).html($('<img src="images/dot.png">'));
                        }
                    }
                });
            });                     
        }
    };
});
```

As you can see, I have a for-loop, and inside the for loop, I have function for ajax-call. The purpose is to call the ajax-method 4times, for each iteration of the loop. But instead, it is called 8times, like it where a second loop there.

Here is my controller:

```
var gameApp = angular.module("gameApp", ['ngRoute','ngSanitize']);

gameApp.service('link', function() {
    this.user = false;
});

gameApp.directive('mapActivity', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(function(scope) {
                angular.element('.click#1').addClass('dotted').html($("<img src='images/dot.png'>"));
                var j = null;
                for(var i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'lib/terrain.php',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        data: {i: i},
                        success: function(data) {
                            var randomRuta = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
                            angular.element('.click#'+randomRuta).addClass('monster').html($("<img src='images/blackdot.png' title='"+data+"'>"));

                        },
                        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(thrownError); }
                    });
                    j=i;
                }  
                angular.element('.click').click(function() {
                    if(angular.element(this).hasClass('monster'))
                    {
                        if(confirm('Vill du anfalla monster?'))
                        {
                            alert("Du vann");
                            angular.element('.click.monster'+j).empty();
                            angular.element('.click.monster').removeClass('monster'+j);

                            angular.element('.click.dotted').empty();
                            angular.element('.click.dotted').removeClass('dotted');
                            angular.element(this).addClass('dotted');
                            angular.element('.click.dotted').html($('<img src="images/dot.png">'));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        angular.element('.click.dotted').empty();
                        angular.element('.click.dotted').removeClass('dotted');

                        if(!angular.element(this).hasClass('dotted'))
                        {
                            angular.element(this).addClass('dotted');
                            angular.element(this).html($('<img src="images/dot.png">'));
                        }
                    }
                });
            });                     
        }
    };
});

function makeTableFrom(str) {
    var k = 1;
    result = "";

    for(var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        result += '<tr>';

        for(var j = 1; j <= 20; j++) {
            if(str[k] == '#') {
                result += '<td id=' + k + '">#</td>';
            }
            else if(str[k] == '&') {
                result += '<td class="click" val="water" id="' + k + '">&</td>';
            }
            else {
                result += '<td class="click" id="' + k + '"></td>';
            }

            k++;
        }
        result += '</tr>';
    }
    return result;
}


gameApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/firstpage.html',
            controller  : 'firstPageCtrl'
    })

    .when('/game', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/game.html',
            controller  : 'gameCtrl'
    });

});

gameApp.controller("firstPageCtrl", function($scope,$http,link,$location) {
    $scope.doLogin = function() {
        $http.post("lib/action.php", {username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password}).success(function(data) {
            if(data) {
                link.user = data;
                console.log(link.user);
                $location.path("/game");
            }
        }).error(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    };
});


gameApp.controller("gameCtrl", function($scope,$http,link,$location,$sce,$rootScope) {

    $scope.getMonsters = "1";

    $http.post("lib/action.php", {monsters: $scope.getMonsters}).success(function(data) {
        $scope.result = makeTableFrom(data);
    });

    $scope.safeHtml = function() {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.result);
    };
    if(link.user) {
        /*$scope.message = "fisk";
        console.log(link.user);*/
    } else {
        /*$scope.message = "Ledsen fisk";
        console.log("Är inte satt");*/
    }

});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="gameCtrl">
    <table ng-bind-html="safeHtml()" map-Activity>
    </table>
</div>
```

Anyone who has a clue?

Comment: `scope.$watch(function(scope) {`? That right there is a huge issue. You are basically calling `function(scope) {` every time _anything_ changes in the scope.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv: Yeah, I know. I've notice this. But what should I use instead of scope?

Comment: Nothing. Why would you need that at all?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv: Because I want this line work: angular.element('.click#1').addClass('dotted').html($("<img src='images/dot.png'>"));. All code below is working, but that not that line. It just returns an empty array..

Comment: It's not supposed to return anything. It adds a class and changes the HTML contents of the selected node. The selector itself is the problem (`.click#1`) because `#something` is the way you select elements by `id`. That selector would only match something looking like this: `<div class="click" id="1">` and I'm pretty sure you have `class="click#1"`.

Comment: Also, a jQuery selector has absolutely nothing to do with AngularJS's scope and `$watch`ing it.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv: The result of console.log(angular.element('.click#1')); is an empty array. If I run console.log(angular.element('.click#+randomRuta)); I get an array with a value like this: Object[td#81.click.monster], instead of just Object[]. How can the code below .click#1 work, and not the other one?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv: By writing .click#1 I refer to the ID of that class.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv: If I $watch(result) which contains my html code for my table, the red dot Is printed out as excpected. So it's not wrong with my selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are calling `makeTableFrom` (building the HTML you are trying to manipulate) after the response to `$http.post("lib/action.php"` comes.
The `mapActivity` directive's `link` function on the other hand executes way before that response comes. So the element `angular.element('.click#1')` is referring to does not yet exist.
By wrapping it in `scope.$watch` you are executing it every time something on the scope changes.
`$scope.result = makeTableFrom(data);` definitely changes something on the scope so after the response comes there will be an element that `angular.element('.click#1')` matches (`makeTableFrom` just created it...).
Problem is the whole code inside `scope.$watch` is executed *at least once before* the response comes.
What you need to do is either rethink this whole code or take the short and hacky route and check if the elements you are trying to manipulate exist:

```
scope.$watch(function(scope) {
    if(angular.element('.click#1').size() > 0) {
        ...
    }  
}
```

Another reason that whole `scope.$watch` idea is wrong is because it will be executed in the future also every time you change the scope (`$scope.foo = 'bar').

Comment: @SerigiuParaschiv: Thank you. But If I exclude scope.$watch, the red dot is not printed out, BUT the blacks dot is printed out as expected. Why that? I can't understand why the black dots inside the loop is printed out, but not the red dot.

Comment: Most likely because the success handler of `$.ajax({` inside `for(var i = 1; i <= 4; i++)` executes _after_ the one in `$http.post("lib/action.php"`.

Comment: It seems to work no. Have a look at this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/FkLbuE8c, as you can see, I added a new variable to store the returned data from $http.post, and then use that variable to call my makeTableFrom. I added $watch(result), what do you think of this solution?

Comment: Well yes, you moved `makeTableFrom(data)` outside the `post` call so the HTML is built before `link` executes.

Comment: Yes. What do you mean with "link"?

Comment: Directive linking: `link: function(scope, element, attrs) {`